# What should be the ideal file size and resolution for a Facebook cover photo using photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have 2 tiff images but when I use the 'recommended' size of 851x315 px and then exported as jpeg high quality in Save for Web, the image becomes too pixelated. How should the files be exported ?

Thanks

Comment: @AndrewH Facebook changes the requirements almost yearly and that post is from '11, last updated '12.

Comment: Hi, the answers in that thread are still relevant and still answer your question. You need to keep your image under 100kb otherwise Facebook will compress your image. Some of the others answers help with pixelation for solid colors. See [How can I make sure that my photos display in the highest possible quality?](https://www.facebook.com/help/266520536764594)

Comment: I need to upload 2 product images side by side without getting them cropped once uploaded in facebook, and wanted to know what the ideal file size could be. i have also tried 1920x1020 but the image gets cropped from above and below

Comment: Why are you making your image size 1920x1020 if the Facebook cover photo size is 851x315? You should keep the same ratio. You can save for web as a jpg, just make sure you're under 100kb.

Comment: Well when i made a psd file of 851x315 and scaled down the 2 tiff images it becomes really pixelated. So I was trying other file sizes without much success so far.

Comment: You scaled down a tiff image and it becomes pixelated? Is it pixelated in Photoshop? Sounds like you are either zoomed in past 100% or you're working with low-quality images to begin with. There isn't enough information here to give you a specific answer.

Comment: Yeah in photoshop and  it has never happened to me before either. I am not sure if its a software problem now. The original images are large tiff files so like you said, when i scale them down it should not be becoming pixelated.

Comment: I am going to try on a different system meanwhile

Comment: @user122309 Set the zoom to 100% in Photoshop.  It should not be pixelated. Don't zoom in, or you will see pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I just googled this and landed here: https://www.facebook.com/help/125379114252045 so apparently the size you have is correct:

> Loads fastest as an sRGB JPG file that's 851 pixels wide, 315 pixels tall and less than 100 kilobytes.

If its too pixelated, your source file may be the problem, or the way you compress the cover. Try to save a 2x JPG or reduce the compression if file size is not a concern.

Comment: I scaled it to 2x JPG and it worked! Thank you